# smd vs toroidal RF filter coils: best choice and for which frequency ranges in receivers

Tags: rf, filter, coil, receiver

Is there a preferred choice for receiver RF filter coils between smd vs toroidal ?

If yes, for which reason and is it based on the range of frequencies they have to be used ? For example HF vs UHF ?

Edit: After you design your filter, for example a 5 poles Chebyshev passband centered on 21 MHz and 8 MHz bandwidth, and you get the values of the capacitors and coils, how should you select bewteen SMD and toroidal coils ?

Could you have better behavior from one or the other coil type ?

I'm asking because I had bad performance by an FM bandstop built with SMDs while the same design and coils values performed really better using toroids. The second was actually silencing almost every station while the first showed poor attenuation.

Comment: I think size IS important so, to answer your question YES there is a preferred choice. Now if you want to ask a more pointed and relevant question please feel free.

Comment: Real engineers base their choice of a component on it's performance which is described in a **datasheet**. They do not choose based on **type or shape** although often a certain type leads to a certain performance.

Comment: i edited the question to give more context / detail.   I'm actually wondering if in this context a certain type can lead to better performance.

Comment: So, in your chebyshev example, how tolerant is the design of coil/inductor series resistance and leakage parallel capacitance. Also how good is the inductor at working at these frequencies. If the data sheet doesn't tell you then I have no hesitation in saying that they are unsuitable. Also, how much shielding did the inductors need to avoid cross talk that might kill the desired response? Your last paragraph tells of a scenario that makes no sense to me - please re-read what you put and amend or explain.

Comment: Hello Andy and thank you for your kind reply.
RF is out my field of study and I'm trying to learn online, so forgive errors I can make in trying to express the subject.
I'm at my second filter design with Elsie and I was just referring to my previous experience (the FM band stop filter) now that I would like to build other filters. 
So the last paragraph is just an example of a previous situation. Probably my english is not good enough to correctly express that. Just don't consider it since it was just an additional thought.

Comment: I believe the answer to my question is already in your comment and I will certainly look again for the datasheets of the involved components.  About the shielding: I looked at various photos of other people builds for same frequency range and seen no shielding between the inductors, just the instructions to place them perpendicular to each other to avoid cross talk. Will do so also in the next build like I did previously and add shields to see the effects. Also, a friend just told me to replace the SMDs with new ones having bought them on eBay, since they could be ... not the top quality :-)

Comment: I thought there could be some sort of general advice for different types depending on the frequency and I now understand this is not the case.   I'll keep learning....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toroids, with a closed magnetic path, will have much lower stray magnetic fields to be picked up by other inductors, as well as picking up much less from other inductors.

So one possible difference between the two filter implementations is coupling between the separate inductors.

Test this by isolating each inductor on the SMD filter (removing capacitors, cutting tracks etc), applying signal to one inductor and measuring what (amplitude and phase) each other inductor picks up. 
Repeat for each inductor in the filter.

If it reveals nothing, you have eliminated this hypothesis and move on to the next answer.

Otherwise, this will give you some idea of the coupling (stray inductances) between components - what do you do next?

1. Add inductors to your simulation model, reflecting the worst few culprits, and see if that explains most of the measured discrepancies.
2. Rotate inductances while measuring, you may be able to arrive at a component placement that eliminates most of the coupling by locating inductors normal to each other.
3. Experiment with screening (cut thin copper sheet to make walls between inductances or screening cans around the worst offenders
4. Replace one or more with toroids (or "screened" versions of the same inductor)
5. Possibly add further components to add out-of-phase versions of the coupled signal to cancel [(aka "neutralize")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrodyne) some of the coupling.

until you have achieved a satisfactory compromise between performance, cost and difficulty of assembly.

Comment: Hello Brian and thank you for your kind answer.  
I will certainly follow the process you described.   
About screening: as an alternative to thin copper sheet, do you think I could cut single or double sided PCB and solder them as walls between the inductances ?  
At this point I would rebuild the whole thing in this way and I have plenty of PCB boards to cut...  
Will do this when I'll move to the new home in December but would like to update this thread with my results.

Comment: blank PCB is a good substitute esp. for prototype, 0.8mm is easier to cut if you have it.